# pairing two objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

how can i create an pair of array objects from an array?

```
   let arrofObj = [ {name:"test1"},
                    {name:"test2"},
                    {name:"test3"},
                    {name:"test4"},
                    {name:"test5"} ]
```

expected output

```
  let output = [[{name:"test1"},{name:"test2"}],
                [{name:"test3"},{name:"test4"}], 
                [{name:"test5"}]]
```

i have tried using array.entries() method but i am not able to pair them

Comment: there is no magical function to do so. you need to iterate and chunk by size. btw, what have you tried?